# Products are not showing in Category Page in Magento

Tags: magento

I have Magento installed on my server. The problem is the products are not showing in the category page although the product is working fine when I access it using direct url like www.mySite.com/dummy-product.html. I have checked by Re-indexing, Flusing Cache, Bulk Disable/Enable the products but no result.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Few things to check

```
Product visibilty must be Catalog or Catalog,Search
Products must be Enabled.
Check product in stock and quantity must be greater than 0
If you are using mutiple website check to which website product points
```

I think this would solve.:)

Answer (score 1):

If your Magento products are not showing up in frontend category pages, that can be because one or more of the below points are not done correctly.

The products must have following set correctly to appear in the category pages in frontend. You can check all the below things in Manage Products screen of any individual product.

```
- Status must be Enabled (under General tab)
- Visiblility should be Catalog OR Catalog, Search (under General tab)
- Stock Qty (quantity) should be greater than Qty for Item’s Status to Become Out  
  of  stock (under Inventory tab)
- Stock Availability must be IN STOCK
- Category should be assigned (under Categories tab)
- Website must be assigned (under Websites tab)
- Clear the cache, re-index the indexes related to product (Product prices, Product flat data and Category products) and everything should work as expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I was not able to get the product appear in search earlier. I had two configurable attributes for my product: shape and size (earlier to be applied to selected products: configurable products). The shape and size attributes were said to be only applied to "configurable products" not "simple products" (this was the problem!).

The associated products that we create (from configurable products) are actually simple products. So Magento requires the attributes we created for the creating configurable products should be with "Simple Products" option.

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Size > Apply to > Selected Product Types > Simple Product

Then this attribute can be used to create attribute set and that in turn to create a configurable product (and this is used to create simple associated products).

Please make sure the product attributes are applied to "simple products" in the Manage Attributes section of the admin.

You might have to delete your earlier associated products (created with configurable attribute). After doing this the configurable product starts appearing in search.

Comment: Some of my configurable products were also not appearing in search result. I had to set associated products correctly and they started appearing in search result.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0. Go to Manage Products->select the product->Inventory. Set the stock quantity to some value, and set Stock Availability to "In Stock". It worked for me, and the product is now showing.

Other possibilities:

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. Refresh your Cache/Indices, just to make sure.